# Evaluate $\iiint_W x^2 \cos z\,dv$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\displaystyle\iiint_{W}{x^2\cos z \ dv}$$

Where $W$ is the region bounded by $z=0, z=\pi, y=0, y=1,$ and $x+y=1$.

I drew the region $W$ at home and found that it is a uniform triangular prism of height $\pi$.

I then made the region of integration $[0,1]\times [0,1-x]\times [0,\pi]$ and made the order of integration $dy\ dx\ dz$. However, because the integral of $\cos(z)$ is $-\sin(z)$, and both $\sin(0)$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$, the entire answer ends up being $0$. I know that usually when finding the volume. Some variable will be put in terms of the the other two. Like, for example, using $\gamma(x,y)$ in my limits for $z$.

Just as I have $\phi(x)=1-x$ in my limits for y. I can do this usually, but I don't have an equation relating all three variables. I tried making one by finding the equation of a plane that involves all 3 variables but I didn't get far. I also can't change see a good way to do a change of variables here. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z$ has no constraints and isn't coupled to $x$ or $y$. So for all $x,y$ the integral over $z$ is always on $[0,\pi]$. So the answer is 0. Perhaps you have an error in the expression for the region?

Comment: No, this is the region given to us in the book. I kept getting that the answer was 0 but I thought I had messed up. Thanks for the help!